# Count double entries in 2 rows no more than 3 times

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, countif

I’d like to count how many times a certain company is audited according to a certain standard. If a company XYZ in a column F is audited according to a certain standard in a column C more than 3 times, it should count as 3. If this company is audited 3 times or less, it should count as it is.

Here is the example (column H is the desired result):

[image]

I have tried to solve it with the following formula:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(($F$2:F2=F2)*($C$2:C2=C2))=1,COUNTIFS($F$2:$F$60000,F2,$C$2:$C$60000,C2),"")
```

However, I only get the results how many times a certain company is audited to a certain standard. The issue with “count no more than 3 times” is missing :-(

I would appreciate any support, no matter whether with a formula or VBA!

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement a `MIN()` statement, e.g: in `H2` try:

```
=IF(OR(C2<>C1,F2<>F1),MIN(3,COUNTIFS(C$2:C$60000,C2,F$2:F$60000,F2)),"")
```

And drag down. Swap the `OR()` back to `SUMPRODUCT()` if need be.

Comment: Is there also a way to convert it into a macro? It takes at least 30 minutes, when I drag this formula in all 60,000 rows...

Answer (score 3):

Untested, since I cannot paste your screenshot of data into a worksheet:

```
IF(
SUMPRODUCT(
      ($F$2:F2=F2)*($C$2:C2=C2)
                            )=1,
          MIN(3,COUNTIFS(
                                $F$2:$F$60000,F2,$C$2:$C$60000,C2)),
             "")
```